# How to create migrations from library project by targeting a Web Api project and use the lib project as the migrations assembly?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I created a .Net 5 Web Api project and a library project. In the library project I created a database entity, a context and an extension to register the context on startup

```
public static IServiceCollection AddContexts(this IServiceCollection services)
    => services.AddDbContext<CarsContext>(x => x.UseNpgsql("Host=host;Database=db;Username=user;Password=pw"));
```

In the Web Api project I call the `AddContexts` method in the startup file. With the EF cli I want to generate migrations in the lib project by calling this in the Api directory

```
dotnet ef migrations add Init --startup-project . -o ./LibProj
```

The build succeeds but unfortunately I get this error

> Your target project 'ApiProj' doesn't match your migrations assembly
> 'LibProj'. Either change your target project or change your migrations
> assembly. Change your migrations assembly by using
> DbContextOptionsBuilder. E.g. options.UseSqlServer(connection, b =>
> b.MigrationsAssembly("ApiProj")). By default, the migrations assembly
> is the assembly containing the DbContext. Change your target project
> to the migrations project by using the Package Manager Console's
> Default project drop-down list, or by executing "dotnet ef" from the
> directory containing the migrations project.

I don't think my Api project should deal with database related things. Is there a way I can fix my command to use the Api project as the startup project but take the context from the lib project and put the migrations into the lib project?

Comment: I will answer your question later .

Comment: @zolty13 this would be really nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--project` flag for the `dotnet ef` command as well:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Init --startup-project ./ApiProj --project ./LibProj -o ./LibProj
```

The `--project` flag sets the target project. Change the paths for each flag as needed, but I think that should give you what you need.

Comment: ahh, that's nice. The command I was looking for was `dotnet ef migrations add Init --startup-project ./ApiProj --project ./LibProj`. I don't need -o anymore because I want to use the default migrations directory :)

Answer (score 1):

To run this commands from your library project you can Add packages to your library project:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

After that you can ran ef commands from your library folder and reference it to your ApiProj.
Example:

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ../ApiProj migrations add init
dotnet ef --startup-project ../ApiProj database update
```